# ConcurrentModificationException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a text adventure in java gui. I have just started this project and I am trying to get the game to realize when a player types "get" + the item. I want it to take the item out of the current ArrayList it is in and add it to the inventory screen I have made. Currently everything works correctly except for when I type a different command like "look". All it should show then is the room description, but it hows the description and picks up the item and puts it in the inventory screen. Then I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at Gamegui.processCommands(Gamegui.java:327)
at Gamegui.playerInputKeyPressed(Gamegui.java:359)
at Gamegui.access$200(Gamegui.java:14)
at Gamegui$3.keyPressed(Gamegui.java:171)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6483)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6302)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Here is my relative code.

processCommands

```
public void processCommands(String input)
{
    ArrayList<String> items = currentRoom.getItems();

    if(input.equals("look"))
    {
        gameScreen.append("\n" + currentRoom.getDescription());
    }
    for(String item : items)
    {
        if(input.equals("get " + item));
        {
            items.remove(item);
            gameScreen.append("\nYou pick up the " + item);
            invScreen.append("\n" + item);
            playerInput.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

playerInputKeyPressed

```
private void playerInputKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_ENTER)
    {
        getInput();
        if(validCommands(inputText)) 
        {
            processCommands(inputText);
        }
        else
        {
            gameScreen.append("\nI don't Understand");
        }

        playerInput.setText("");

        try
        {
            JScrollBar sb = gameScreenPlace.getVerticalScrollBar();
            sb.setValue(sb.getMaximum());
        }
        catch(java.lang.NullPointerException err)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: OK, the obvious question -- which line is `Gamegui.java:327`, the one that the exception message tells you is causing your problem?

Comment: Yout remove items inside iterating elements;

Comment: Yep, use an Iterator to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your removing items while iterating.

```
   for(String item : items)
    {
        if(input.equals("get " + item));
        {
            items.remove(item);
            gameScreen.append("\nYou pick up the " + item);
            invScreen.append("\n" + item);
            playerInput.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Use an Iterator and call remove for this manner.

```
Iterator<String> iter = items.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String str = iter.next();

   if(input.equals("get " + str))
        {
        iter.remove();
        gameScreen.append("\nYou pick up the " + str);
        invScreen.append("\n" + str);
        playerInput.setText("");
        }

}
```

For [reference](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-how-to-handle-concurrent-modification-exception/).

Also remove semicolon to this line.

```
`if(input.equals("get " + str))`
```

Comment: Well I do not get the error doing it this way, but If I type "get" without the item it goes to my inv screen. And if i type look, it displays the room description, and puts the item in the inv screen. I cannot figure out why

Comment: No problem. You can accept this answer by clicking the check in my answer to resolve this problem. Also, you can upvote or downvote an answer if you like them or not.

Comment: Thanks for that advice as well. I'm pretty new to this.